# Javascript Regular Expression filter for catching special characters that need to be escaped is producing weird results

Tags: javascript, regex

I am writing some code in javascript that will look at text being loaded on to a page from a database and check for profanity/vulgar words. The text is personal opinions that have been recorded from a survey/assessment/evaluation. I have a bad word json file that is read in with javascript to create a regular expression to be used to check the text. When it is read in, it is also run through a function that replaces letters/vowels with alternative characters/special characters. Everything seems to be working fine except this one issue I am having with the @ and the $ characters. I am able to catch the word "a$$hole" but not "a$$".

I have tried to use the escaping function because the word(s) has/have special characters. I have tried using the escape character itself in the function that replaces the letters/vowels with alternates. The fact that the code will catch "a$$hole" but not "a$$" just has me completely baffled.

I am working in vanilla javascript only, with no libraries. I am not allowed to use any libraries. I cannot change these restrictions, so please don't suggest third party software or additional libraries as part of the answer.

I have included the code I am using for testing. I don't know how to get a json file attached to the snippet so it will run the same way I am doing it, so I have added a partial of it as just code. It is the part that contains the words that should be relevant to the issue. I also included a screen shot of the results that I get when it runs from Visual Studio.

Screen shots of results:

[Highlighted words found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHwgR.png)

[Words replaced that were found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWsAR.png)

[Console log of words converted with the alternates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0Bm4.png)

Screen shot of json file:

[Json file of the words that begin with "a" (partial)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqJNi.png)

```js
    async function fetchData() {
        let response = await fetch("badwords.json");
        let data = await response.json();
        data = JSON.stringify(data);
        data = JSON.parse(data);

        const badWords = data;
        const badWordsRegexString = "\\b(" + badWords.map(convertToL337).join("|") + ")\\b";
        const badWordsRegex = new RegExp(badWordsRegexString, 'ig');

        const userReview1 = document.getElementById('leetText').textContent;

        const censored1 = userReview1.replace(badWordsRegex,
            badWord => "*".repeat(badWord.length));

        const highlight1 = userReview1.replace(badWordsRegex, '<mark>$&</mark>');
        const count1 = userReview1.match(badWordsRegex);
        let total = count1.length;

        function convertToL337(word) {
            // Replace all vowels with alternations of their l33t alternatives:
            const l337 = { a: "4@", e: "3&", i: "1!\|", o: "0*<>", u: "v", s: "$", t: "7" };
            let convert = word.replace(/[aeioust]/gi, c => `[${c}${l337[c]}]+`);
            return convert;
        }
        
        document.getElementById('filteredText').textContent = censored1;
        document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = "Total vulgarities/profanities is: " + total;
        document.getElementById('leetText').innerHTML = highlight1;

    } fetchData();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="badwords.json"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Original Text </h2>    
    <pre id="leetText">
        L337 text:
        This is an ass @ss a$$ test to b1tch see if cocksuck3r is catching cunt profanity or fuck vulger sh!t words or tw4t text.
        This is also a a$$hole check to see if it will do l3itch or b!tch
        more than sentence and spit it wh0re out correctly back to the suckmyc0ck page bi.
    </pre>
    <pre id="count"></pre>
    <h2>Filtered Text</h2>
    <pre id="filteredText"></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Json file: badwords.json
This is only the a's, and words that are shown in the screen shot so it can be copied and saved for testing above script.

[  "abbo",
"abo",
"alligatorbait",
"anal",
"analannie",
"analsex",
"angie",
"anus",
"areola",
"argie",
"arian",
"arse",
"arsehole",
"aryan",
"ass",
"@ss",
"a$$",
"a$s",
"as$",
"assbang",
"assbagger",
"assblaster",
"assclown",
"asscowboy",
"asses",
"assfuck",
"assfucker",
"asshat",
"asshole",
"assholes",
"asshore",
"assjockey",
"asskiss",
"asskisser",
"assklown",
"asslick",
"asslicker",
"asslover",
"assman",
"assmonkey",
"assmunch",
"assmuncher",
"asspacker",
"asspirate",
"asspuppies",
"assranger",
"asswhore",
"asswipe",
"autoerotic",
"autoerotica",
"bi",
"bitch"
"l3itch",
"13itch",
"cocksucker",
"cunt",
"fuck",
"fucknut"
"shit",
"suckmycock",
"twat",
"whore"
]

Comment: It is because words like `@ss` and `a$$` do not consist of word chars only, they start / end with non-word chars, and when you add `\b` you require a word char to be present immediately before/after this "word". `"\\b(" + badWords.map(convertToL337).join("|") + ")\\b"` must be adjusted to fit your concept of a word. In most situations, `"(?<!\\w)(" + badWords.map(convertToL337).join("|") + ")(?!\\w)"` should be enough

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you. I had tried to do that earlier, but I guess I wrote it wrong as it was catching the "ass" in words like assistant and trying to hide it as well. I just changed the code to match yours and tested it and it does exactly what it is supposed to now. Again, thank you for the help. I dont have a way to accept your comment as the answer though. Does that matter?

Comment: No, it is fine to keep the question as a signpost.